# Why $\sqrt{x^2}$ is not equal to $\big(\sqrt{x}\big)^2$?

Tags: radicals

I'm reading **[Precalculus from James Stewart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1305071751)**. In the book, the author says that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is not equal to $\big(\sqrt{x}\big)^2$. I was performing a couple of proofs and I ended up here:

If you have, for example:

$\sqrt{5^2} ≟ \big(\sqrt{5}\big)^2 \implies (\sqrt{5})² = \sqrt{5}\cdot\sqrt{5} = \sqrt{5}\cdot5 = \sqrt{25} = \big(\sqrt{5}\big)^2$

So, for me, $\sqrt{5^2}= \big(\sqrt{5}\big)^2$.

**Can you proof that I'm wrong?**

Comment: You can't prove a positive proposition by an example.

Comment: @KennyLau Proposition: there exists a Besicovitch set of measure 0. 

I would be very interested if you proved this without an example

Comment: @mathworker21 you obviously know what I meant.

Comment: @KennyLau OP may have accidentally called it a "proof" but he was looking for a counter-example to Stewart's claim. He wasn't trying to prove anything.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek OP wanted us to prove that OP is wrong, which presumes that OP has done any proof at all (his example of $\sqrt{5^2}=(\sqrt5)^2$ obviously cannot be wrong)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is true for all positive and zero $x$, but if $x \lt 0, \sqrt x$ is not defined in the reals, so $(\sqrt x)^2$ is also not defined.  On the other hand $\sqrt {x^2}$ is defined and equals $|x|$ for all real $x$

Comment: I understand your point, but what if you have (√-1)² = √-1.√-1 = √(-1).(-1) = √1² = 1. I'm a bit confused right now

Comment: @leomestizo  Your example is the reason that the full statement of the rule you are trying to use is: $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ provided that not both $a$ and $b$ are negative.

Comment: If you work in the complex numbers you have to be careful about the branch of the square root function you use.  In the reals we agree that the square root sign is always the positive square root.  In the complex plane there is no way to consistently choose the square root to make all the usual real laws of exponents work.  Are you using real or complex numbers?  I assumed reals because your example is real.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt1 = 1$ whereas $(\sqrt{-1})^2 = i^2 = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{a}$ is just a symbol for the following problem: solve for $x$ the equation: $x^2=a$. For positive $a$, this equation has 2 solutions with the same absolute value and opposite sign. Usually the positive solution is indicated by $\sqrt[+]{a}$. So in the end:
$$\sqrt{a}=\pm\sqrt[+]{a},~\forall a\ge0$$

Back to your example:
$$(\sqrt{5})^2=(\pm\sqrt[+]{5})^2=(\sqrt[+]{5})^2=5$$
while
$$\sqrt{5^2}=\pm\sqrt[+]{5^2}=\pm\sqrt[+]{25}=\pm5$$

Comment: $x^2 = -1 \implies x = \pm i$. $a$ need not be positive. Also I have never seen $\sqrt[+]{x}$ stand for positive solution, maybe it is just me.

Comment: @A---B I think that the OP don't know complex numbers, that's why I limited arguments to positive reals only.

Comment: Fine with me.$~~$

Comment: @trying Usually by $\sqrt{u}$ we denote the non-negative number whose square is $u$. Also, for any real number $x,$ $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$ So, by following standard math notation, $\sqrt{5^2}=5>0,$ not $-5.$

Answer (score 0):

You are not wrong about $\sqrt{(5)^2} = \left( \sqrt{5}\right) ^2$.

But if you think that this proves that $\sqrt{(-5)^2}$ is equal to  $\left( \sqrt{-5}\right) ^2$, then you are mistaken.

$\sqrt{(-5)^2} = \sqrt{25} = 5$

While $\left( \sqrt{-5}\right) ^2 = \left( \sqrt{-5}\right)\left( \sqrt{-5}\right) = -5$ (or it does not exist if our domain of discourse if the real numbers.)

Comment: Isn't this answer same as of Kenny ?

Comment: @A---B  I tried to use the OP's example and I tried to include the possibililty that the OP does not know about square roots of negative numbers.

Comment: @JimH hi,I am afraid your first example about $\sqrt{(-5^2)}=\sqrt{25}$ is not right $(-5^2)=-25$ and $(-5)^2=25$

Comment: Because $x=-5$ not just $5$